# Get nested elements array JSON file

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, nested

I have this JSON file with nested array > queue_list.

```
[{
    "id_shop": "2",
    "shop_name": "Brackets",
    "queue_list": [{
        "id_queue_current": "1",
        "queue_name": "Queue 1",
        "queue_current_number": "12"
    }, {
        "id_queue_current": "2",
        "queue_name": "Queue 2",
        "queue_current_number": "23"
    }]
}]
```

With my jQuery/ajax I can read correctly, id_shop and shop_name, but cannot read elements in queue_list. How can I access at this elements?

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "shop_list.php",
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) { 
            data = JSON.parse(data); 
            data.forEach(function(dataItem){
            var id_shop = dataItem.id_shop;
            var shop_name = dataItem.shop_name;
            var queue_current_number = dataItem.current_number;
            var queue_name = dataItem.queue_name; //this element
             $("#header h1").html('<div>'+shop_name+'</div>');
                 $("#shop_queue").html('<li data-categoryId ="'+id_shop+'"><a href="#shop_'+id_shop+'">'+queue_name+'</a></li>');
         });
         }
    });
```

thank your very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try with below solution,

```js
var test = 
[{
    "id_shop": "2",
    "shop_name": "Brackets",
    "queue_list": [{
        "id_queue_current": "1",
        "queue_name": "Queue 1",
        "queue_current_number": "12"
    }, {
        "id_queue_current": "2",
        "queue_name": "Queue 2",
        "queue_current_number": "23"
    }]
}]

     test.forEach(function(dataItem){
            var id_shop = dataItem.id_shop;
            var shop_name = dataItem.shop_name;
            var queue_data = dataItem.queue_list; 
            queue_data.forEach(function(queueItem){
                var queue_id= queueItem.id_queue_current;
                alert(queue_id);
                var queue_name= queueItem.queue_name;
                alert(queue_name);
                var queue_current_number= queueItem.queue_current_number;
                alert(queue_current_number);
            })
         })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do something like this inside your success method

```
var queue_name;

        var queue_lst = dataItem.queue_list.each(function(item, index){
            queue_name=JSON.parse(item).queue_name;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot read and access the elements in `queue_list` by merely calling `dataItem.current_number` or `dataItem.queue_name`. You can access the elements inside the JSON object  `queue_list` by calling elements through `queue_list` like `dataItem.queue_list.current_number` and `dataItem.queue_list.queue_name`.

Hope this solved the problem.